# Effective algorithm of searching the "nearest" doubly stochastic matrix

Tags: optimization, matrices

Given a data matrix $D$, is there any effective algorithm to solve the optimization problem

$\min_Q || D - Q ||_F$

such that

- $Qe=e$,
- $e^TQ=e^T$, and
- $Q_{i,j} \geq 0 $  $\forall i,j$,

where $||\cdot||_F$ is the Frobenius norm of matrix.

p.s. I also [posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288860/effective-algorithm-of-searching-the-nearest-doubly-stochastic-matrix) this question on the Mathematicss exchange.

Comment: Concurrent cross posting is not allowed. Vote to close.

Comment: I think this is better suited here. Maybe Rein can flag the Math@SE question for closing?

Comment: Sorry for cross posting, I already flagged the post in Math.SE to close.

Comment: Because this is a convex quadratic program (by considering the Frobenius norm squared), it can be approximated to exponential precision in polynomial time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a special case of the following problem: given a polytope $P$ specified by linear constraints and a point $x$ find $y \in P$ that minimizes $\|x - y\|_2^2$.

If you are ok with a small *additive* approximation to $\|x - y\|_2^2$, you can try using the Frank-Wolfe algorithm. This is a sort of gradient descent algorithm. You start from a point $y_0 \in P$ (in your case this could be say the $n \times n$ matrix with $1/n$ in every coordinate) and in each steps you compute $y_{i+1}$ from $y_i$ as follows:

1. Let $w = x - y_i$.
2. Let $v$ be the vertex of $P$ that maximizes $w^Tz$ for $z \in P$ (can be found by LP).
3. Find the point on the line through $y_i$ and $v$ that is closest to $x$ (this is quadratic optimization in a single variable). This point is $y_{i+1}$.

Ken Clarkson has [analyzed](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=1824777.1824783) this simple algorithm. In $t$ steps, the additive approximation is bounded by $d(P)^2/t$, where $d(P)$ is the diameter of $P$. In your case, I believe $d(P) \leq \sqrt{n}$, as the vertices of $P$ are permutation matrices and they all have Frobenius norm $\sqrt{n}$. So in $O(n/\epsilon)$ iterations of the above algorithm you can get $Q$ such that  $\|D - Q\|_F^2 \leq \|D - Q^*\|_F^2 + \epsilon$, where $Q^*$ is the optimal solution.